# For every $n \geq 2$ there exists an n-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So i was given this question. For every $n \geq 2$ there exists an n-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees. I have seen somewhat similar questions like Given a simple graph with $n = 4k + 2$ vertices. Can the vertices of
this graph have distinct degrees? Is the solution style thee same, I'm confused about this question.

Comment: If $n=2$ this isn't true. Was this a prove or disprove question?

Comment: Are you sure that you weren’t asked to prove that for $n\ge 2$ there does **not** exist an $n$-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees? Because that statement is true, and **N. S.** has given some useful hints for proving it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** What can be the degrees of vertices in a simple graph with $n$ vertices?

**Hint 2** What does it mean if they are all different?

**Hint 3** What does the largest degree mean? What about the smallest?